# Magento rewrite Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, collection, catalog

I'm doing a rewrite of: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid

I already done most of the job on my custom module. The function getStoreRestrictions() returns an array of all available stores view ids to that user

ex: user No.1 has stores 1, 2, 4

User No.2 has store 3

User No.3 has all stores

The problem I'm having is on the `_prepareCollection()` on the edit column. the idea is that when the user clicks edit they can only edit the parameters of the storeview instead of the global parameters of the product. I was able to modify the storeswitcher and works fine. now my problem is when the catalog is loaded the first time and there is no `$this->getRequest()->getParam('store')` because that parameter is empty. I'm trying to make to where when they go to the product catalog they can see the products for the first storeview they have allowed unless they change that using the storeswitcher.

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Block_Rewrite_AdminCatalogProductGrid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
{
protected function _getStore()
 {
    $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
    $storeIds = Namespace_Module_Model_Module::getStoreRestrictions();
    if(!empty($storeIds) && $storeId == 0){
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeIds[0]);
    }else{
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }
 }

 protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
        $collection->joinField('qty',
            'cataloginventory/stock_item',
            'qty',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
            'left');
    }
    if ($store->getId()) {
        //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
        $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
        $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'name',
            'catalog_product/name',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $adminStore
        );
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'custom_name',
            'catalog_product/name',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $store->getId()
        );
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'status',
            'catalog_product/status',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $store->getId()
        );
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'visibility',
            'catalog_product/visibility',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner',
            $store->getId()
        );
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'price',
            'catalog_product/price',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'left',
            $store->getId()
        );
    }
    else {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    }

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    parent::_prepareCollection();
    $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
    return $this;
}

 protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('entity_id',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
            'width' => '50px',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'index' => 'entity_id',
    ));
    $this->addColumn('name',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
            'index' => 'name',
    ));

    $store = $this->_getStore();
    if ($store->getId()) {
        $this->addColumn('custom_name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name in %s', $store->getName()),
                'index' => 'custom_name',
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('type',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
            'width' => '60px',
            'index' => 'type_id',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
    ));

    $sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
        ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
        ->load()
        ->toOptionHash();

    $this->addColumn('set_name',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attrib. Set Name'),
            'width' => '100px',
            'index' => 'attribute_set_id',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => $sets,
    ));

    $this->addColumn('sku',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'index' => 'sku',
    ));

    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $this->addColumn('price',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
            'type'  => 'price',
            'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
            'index' => 'price',
    ));

    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
        $this->addColumn('qty',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
                'width' => '100px',
                'type'  => 'number',
                'index' => 'qty',
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('visibility',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visibility'),
            'width' => '70px',
            'index' => 'visibility',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_visibility')->getOptionArray(),
    ));

    $this->addColumn('status',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
            'width' => '70px',
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray(),
    ));

    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('websites',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Websites'),
                'width' => '100px',
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'websites',
                'type'      => 'options',
                'options'   => Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->toOptionHash(),
        ));
    }

    if ($store->getId()) {
    echo "testing";
    $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'     => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'     => array(
                        'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                        'params'=>array('store'=>$store->getId())
                    ),
                    'field'   => 'id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
    ));
    }else{
    $this->addColumn('action',
        array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'     => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                array(
                    'caption' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'     => array(
                        'base'=>'*/*/edit',
                        'params'=>array('store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'))
                    ),
                    'field'   => 'id'
                )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
    ));
    }

    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Rss')) {
        $this->addRssList('rss/catalog/notifystock', Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Notify Low Stock RSS'));
    }

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
}
```

Comment: And where is your problem?

Comment: the rewrite works, but I don't know how to make work the part I say about click edit and edit only the product storeview they are allowed. also I don't have any idea how to do the store switcher to work.

Comment: Code modified to explain better. please check and let me know if makes more sense and if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

the problem was that I was missing a function overwrite:

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    $store = $this->_getStore();
    if($store->getId()){
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
        'store'=>$store->getId(),
        'id'=>$row->getId())
    );
    }else{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
        'store'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('store'),
        'id'=>$row->getId())
    );
    }
}
```

that way when you have a storeId that is provided by the `_getStore()` this will give each row the proper URL when the user comes to the catalog->manage products for the first time and they are not allowed to modify the default global values.